# How to improve lambda performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Hi I am trying to understand the lambda architecture in depth. Below is my understanding about lambda.

Whenever we create lambda function, container will spin up. If we select python as run time the python container will spin up. Now there is cold start. For example, If we dint call lambda for long time, container will become inactive. It will call new container and it will take some time to spin up new container. This is cold start. Now I am bit confused here. If I want to avoid this delay what is the right approach? We can trigger lambda every 5 min using cloud watch. Any other good approaches to handle this? 
Also there is /tmp folder where we can store static files. So /tmp is not part of container? Whenever new container spins up, /tmp data will be lost or remain? Can someone help me to understand this concepts and tell me to use best approaches to handle this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is any kind of container spinning up during a cold start. It's just your python application being loaded into the environment that might take some time during a cold start, which is at max a couple of seconds. Since just recently, you can [configure *Provisioned Concurrency* to avoid cold starts alltogether](https://devclass.com/2019/12/04/aws-warms-lambda-devs-hearts-promises-end-to-cold-starts/).

Comment: But this means if max. two or three seconds delay during a cold start is acceptable for your solution, cold starts shouldn't concern you at all anyways.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. So we dont have to follow any best practices now and AWS handles it for us? Also can you tell me what is /tmp in lambda?

Comment: I can't tell for sure but do not expect the data in /tmp to be available across invocations. It's probably only available during a single invocation.

Comment: Are you running into any issues?  The power of Lambda is in scalability.  You can, by default, run 1000 instances simultaneously.  If you're worried about persistent local store then you're thinking about this wrong - do you want local store across all 1000 instances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You are correct there is a cold start issue but it's been observed that it depends on a lot of factors(runtime, memory, zip size....for e.g. a java lambda will have more cold start compared to python) and basically it was a big problem for lambdas inside a user-defined VPC. wherein there is an overhead of creating an elastic network interface and then invoking the lambda. But the recent rollout has changed this and now you should not see this problem. [improved-vpc-networking for lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/).
- Also just in the reinvent 2019 aws have announced the [Provisioned Concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/aws-lambda-announces-provisioned-concurrency/) So for lambda Functions using Provisioned Concurrency will execute with consistent start-up latency.
- With Provisioned Concurrency, functions can instantaneously serve a
  burst of traffic with consistent start-up latency for every invoke up
  to the specified scale. Customers only pay for the amount of concurrency that they configure and for the period of time that it is configured.
- Regarding the `/tmp` please note that Each Lambda function receives 512MB of non-persistent disk space in its own /tmp directory. So you cannot rely on it. [Lambda limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) If you are looking for persistent storage you should be using S3.

Comment: This 500MB space inside container?

Comment: To be precise its 512MB. Hope this link helps its got other limitations on lambda as well https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html